# PyCharm - how to get rid of "Undefined step reference" warning

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd, python-behave

I am making a Python BDD testing framework based on https://github.com/spyoungtech/behave-webdriver by using PyCharm Professional IDE. I followed the instruction from README file and the framework IS working. Although I'm getting a very annoying problem. PyCharm is giving me an error/warning in all of my *.feature files which are using step definitions from behave-webdriver, saying "undefined step reference" and what is even more annoying, because of that I cannot use ctrl+click to navigate to the step definition of these steps. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

PS. FYI. My step definition file is basically empty with just one line "from behave_webdriver.steps import *", and PyCharm is marking this line INCORRECTLY as "unused import statement", although without this line my code is not working (I'm getting "undefined step" error).

Comment: PyCharm can't handle step imports, unfortunately. I created a ticket in PyCharms bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported an issue on behave-webdriver GitHub and they already fixed it in their code. More details about this problem you can find here: https://github.com/spyoungtech/behave-webdriver/issues/75
I suppose that it will be officially added to the next release (0.3.0) so this problem won't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm makes it very easy to [disable/supress inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html).

To disable an inspection, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, select inspections, then disable the one you want.

To suppress an inspection, which only stops highlighting, hit the arrow displayed next to the inspection, and click "suppress for ___"

Comment: Thank you for the answer but turning off inspection is not satisfying. Probably the title of my problem is misleading... The warning which I'm getting is only a symptom of the real issue, which is: PyCharm cannot bind steps declaration from an external library (behave-webdriver) with steps itself (in *.feature file)